# vis.gam spatial interaction output as a raster grid instead of plot object

Tags: r, interpolation, modelling, gam

I am trying to create an object that can be put into tmap or another GIS platform from my model output. I created a model using the gamm4 package that has a spatial interaction term. See an example below (note: this example doesn't actually make sense but gives an X, Y interaction plot)

```
library(geoR)
library(gamm4)
data(gambia)

fit<- gamm4(age~ s(X,Y) +s(green))

vis.gam(fit13$gam, view = c('X','Y'), plot.type = 'contour', too.far = 0.10)
```

This should produce a plot like this.

[image]

I want to convert this plot to a raster object, so that I can use it for a tmap or leaflet map, but I don't really know where to begin. Do I generate an empty raster of my study area and then populate it with the gamm output somehow? Some kind of interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close - create a grid of X-Y values and a single value of `green` (or other covariates) and use `predict`.

Fit the model:

```
fit <- gamm4(age~ s(x,y) +s(green),data=gambia)
```

Make a 150x100 grid over the coordinate space. Some adjustment needed if you'd like square pixels, but this will serve for now:

```
xs = seq(min(gambia$x), max(gambia$x), len=150)
ys = seq(min(gambia$y), max(gambia$y), len=100)
```

That's the cell coordinates, we need all covariates over the grid and `vis.gam` seems to use the median of the data, which is stored in the `fit$gam$var.summary` object:

```
xy = expand.grid(x=xs, y=ys, green=fit$gam$var.summary$green[2])
```

Now predict over those values:

```
pp = predict.gam(fit$gam, newdata=xy)
```

and reshape to a matrix:

```
ppm = matrix(pp, nrow=length(xs))
```

which you can display to check you got it right:

```
image(x=xs, y=ys, z=ppm)
```

[image]

Then its some matrix fiddling and extent calculation to get it into a format to feed into a `terra` function:

```
 library(terra)
 m = list(x=xs, y=ys, z=ppm)
 image(m)
 resx <- ( m$x[length(m$x)] - m$x[1] ) / (length(m$x)-1)
 resy <- ( m$y[length(m$y)] - m$y[1] ) / (length(m$y)-1)
    xmn <- min(m$x) - 0.5 * resx
    xmx <- max(m$x) + 0.5 * resx
    ymn <- min(m$y) - 0.5 * resy
    ymx <- max(m$y) + 0.5 * resy
  z <- t(m$z)
  z <- z[nrow(z):1, ]
```

So you can do:

```
  lp <- rast(z, extent=c(xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx))
  plot(lp)
```

[image]